# Use fstab to mount luks encrypted drive to subfolder within home

Tags: fstab, luks, automounting, lubuntu

Fresh install of Lubuntu 20.04 on system with Windows 10 and Lubuntu installed on 256GB NVME drive to dual boot.

Boot drive is /dev/nvme0n1p2
Home folder is therefore /dev/nvme0n1p2/home/username

I have a 1TB HDD with two partitions:

/dev/sda1 736GB encrypted ext4/LUKS
/dev/sda2 195GB ntfs

For context, the purpose of the ntfs partition is so that I can easily share files between my Lubuntu environment and Windows 10.

My objective is to be able to:

1. Boot into Lubuntu
2. Log in
3. Open File Manager and navigate to /home/Filestore
4. Be prompted to enter password

I have read this guide:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/how-to-automount-file-systems-on-linux

And I can successfully automount the ntfs drive to /home/WindowsShare

But I cannot mount the LUKS filesystem to /home/Filestore

Using 'ext4' as the filesystem gives me this error message:

```
mount: /home/luke/Filestore: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

The entry for the partition in blkid is:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="redacted" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="redacted"
```

So I therefore tried using "crypto_LUKS" as the filesystem in fstab and got this:

```
mount: /home/luke/Filestore: unknown filesystem type 'crypto_LUKS'.
```

I have looked for guides on automounting encrypted filesystems and found numerous. Here is one:

https://blog.tinned-software.net/automount-a-luks-encrypted-volume-on-system-start/

Everything I have found involves using a shared key to auto-decrypt the filesystem on boot. I don't want to do this as I don't have an encrypted area on my boot drive in order to store the key.

Is my stated aim possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lsblk` to find the partition you have LUKS encryption on

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0 232.9G  0 part 
├─sda2        8:2    0   1.9G  0 part 
├─sda3        8:3    0    94M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda4        8:4    0  93.1G  0 part 
... and so on
```

Suppose you have LUKS block on `sda1`, then you enter the following entry on `/etc/crypttab`:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/crypttab
<name>    /dev/sda1    <password file path>
```

Here, the 'name' will be from the `/dev/mapper/<name>` path but without the '/dev/mapper' part. Then it will be followed by the device path. After that, the path of the password file (the password must be in plaintext and not followed by new , if you want to automatically unlock the partition during bootup. Otherwise, if you don't give that path, a password prompt will appear during bootup.

Now, enter the partition entry to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/<name> /mnt/mountpoint auto <options> 0 0
```

Now reboot your machine.